# Meaning of ? mark in SQLite

Tags: php, zend-framework, sqlite

What does the `?` character in this SQL query mean?

```
$res = $dbConn->fetchPairs('SELECT name FROM tree where parent = ?',$key);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a parameterized query. The ? is a placeholder for the actual value stored in $key.

Comment: hi chrissr, thanks for the answer... your answer get me strait to the point ... anyhow ImSleeping answer is also another point for further reading..

Answer (score 5):

It's a query [parameter](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam). The value isn't known at compile time - it is determined at runtime by using the contents of the variable $key.

Other notations also exist for specifying parameters:

```
 ?NNN    A question mark followed by a number NNN holds a spot for the NNN-th
         parameter. NNN must be between 1 and SQLITE_MAX_VARIABLE_NUMBER.
    ?    A question mark that is not followed by a number holds a spot for the
         next unused parameter.
:AAAA    A colon followed by an identifier name holds a spot for a named
         parameter with the name AAAA. Named parameters are also numbered. The
         number assigned is the next unused number. To avoid confusion, it is
         best to avoid mixing named and numbered parameters.
@AAAA    An "at" sign works exactly like a colon.
$AAAA    A dollar-sign followed by an identifier name also holds a spot for a
         named parameter with the name AAAA. The identifier name in this case
         can include one or more occurances of "::" and a suffix enclosed in
         "(...)" containing any text at all. This syntax is the form of a
         variable name in the Tcl programming language. The presence of this
         syntax results from the fact that SQLite is really a Tcl extension
         that has escaped into the wild.
```

Answer (score 2):

Typically used in what's called. [stored procedures or prepared-statements](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/4.1/prepared-statements.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a substitution, like in printf they use %1, %2, etc.; the ? is the replacement for $key.

Comment: Why did I get a downvote? It was a valid attempt at an answer, 4 answers in 15 seconds with the same answer, and this is voted down?

Comment: I'm guessing you got a -1 because parameterization is more than just string substitution - it's also a countermeasure against SQL injection attacks, because it doesn't dump raw text into your queries.

Comment: Oh I see, I did not know that before. :D Yay for not-hacking.